# krajee bootstrap-fileinput with django framework

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-file-upload

I am trying to use [this, krajee bootstrap-fileinput](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) library with Django python framework. I need to pass `csrf_token` via headers to submit the file via ajax to the server. Where should I put csrf_token? In general, I used to pass as a header in ajax method in jquery. Now I don't understand where should I have to include `csrf_token`. Do I have to put in `fileinput`?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is a very old question, here is the answer. I had the same issue with using the bootstrap-file-upload plugin and I solved it by adding the crsf token to as `uploadExtraData`

Laravel adds the token into a globally available variable

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {"csrfToken":"PQwQZyeHaARm0gf52qzvIdl3T203FhmPT90K2bLX"};
</script>
```

You can then make use of it, when assigning the bootstrap-file-upload widget

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#file_uplooad").fileinput({
       uploadUrl:'/ajax/fileupload', 
       uploadExtraData:{
         _token:window.Laravel.csrfToken // we pass it here to the server
       }
    });
 });
```

Although this is a very late answer, I still hope that someone will benefit from it. Have fun!